# Passenger does not recognize application: Message from Phusion: End time can not be before or equal to begin time

Tags: passenger, redmine, phusion

I am receiving this error from the log inside /var/log/httpd/error_log. Which is posted below:

**/var/log/httpd/error_log**

```
    [ E 2020-02-12 18:58:36.8946 2418/Ta age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:276 ]: [Client 2-1] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is c47544c7. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
[Wed Feb 12 19:00:59.940158 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2384] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully

[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:00.9580 2418/T8 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:671 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:00.9582 2418/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1246 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:00.9583 2418/Ta Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.2] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:00.9584 2418/Ta Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.2] Shutdown finished
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:00.9584 2418/Tc Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.3] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:00.9584 2418/Tc Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.3] Shutdown finished
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:00.9587 2418/Tg Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:00.9587 2418/Tg Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:00.9587 2418/T8 Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.1] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:00.9588 2418/T8 Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.1] Shutdown finished
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:00.9588 2418/Te Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.4] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:00.9588 2418/Te Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.4] Shutdown finished
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:01.9473 2418/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1325 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
[Wed Feb 12 19:01:02.056353 2020] [core:notice] [pid 3593] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Wed Feb 12 19:01:02.057393 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 3593] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:02.0819 3595/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1373 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:02.0992 3598/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1340 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:02.0994 3598/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:256 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ W 2020-02-12 19:01:02.1098 3598/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1007 ]: WARNING: potential privilege escalation vulnerability detected. Phusion Passenger is running as root, and part(s) of the Passenger root path (/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/passenger-6.0.4) can be changed by non-root user(s):

 - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/passenger-6.0.4 is not secure: it can be modified by user redmine
 - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems is not secure: it can be modified by user redmine
 - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5 is not secure: it can be modified by group rvm
 - /usr/local/rvm/gems is not secure: it can be modified by group rvm
 - /usr/local/rvm is not secure: it can be modified by group rvm

Please either fix up the permissions for the insecure paths, or install Passenger in a different location that can only be modified by root.
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:02.1098 3598/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1015 ]: Passenger core online, PID 3598

[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:02.1132 3598/T8 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:671 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:02.1133 3598/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1246 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:02.1133 3598/Ta Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.2] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:02.1134 3598/Ta Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.2] Shutdown finished
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:02.1134 3598/Tc Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.3] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:02.1134 3598/Tc Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.3] Shutdown finished
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:02.1134 3598/Te Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.4] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:02.1134 3598/Te Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.4] Shutdown finished
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:02.1135 3598/T8 Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.1] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:02.1135 3598/T8 Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.1] Shutdown finished
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:02.1136 3598/Tg Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:02.1136 3598/Tg Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ApiServer] Shutdown finished
[Wed Feb 12 19:01:02.123111 2020] [so:warn] [pid 3593] AH01574: module rewrite_module is already loaded, skipping
[Wed Feb 12 19:01:02.124747 2020] [so:warn] [pid 3593] AH01574: module lbmethod_byrequests_module is already loaded, skipping
[Wed Feb 12 19:01:02.163138 2020] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 3593] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:02.1889 3624/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1373 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:02.2063 3627/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1340 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:02.2065 3627/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:256 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ W 2020-02-12 19:01:02.2171 3627/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1007 ]: WARNING: potential privilege escalation vulnerability detected. Phusion Passenger is running as root, and part(s) of the Passenger root path (/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/passenger-6.0.4) can be changed by non-root user(s):

 - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/passenger-6.0.4 is not secure: it can be modified by user redmine
 - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems is not secure: it can be modified by user redmine
 - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5 is not secure: it can be modified by group rvm
 - /usr/local/rvm/gems is not secure: it can be modified by group rvm
 - /usr/local/rvm is not secure: it can be modified by group rvm

Please either fix up the permissions for the insecure paths, or install Passenger in a different location that can only be modified by root.
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:02.2172 3627/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1015 ]: Passenger core online, PID 3627
[Wed Feb 12 19:01:02.235872 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3593] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips mod_fcgid/2.3.9 Phusion_Passenger/6.0.4 PHP/5.4.16 SVN/1.7.14 mod_perl/2.0.11 Perl/v5.16.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Feb 12 19:01:02.235906 2020] [core:notice] [pid 3593] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:03.1207 3598/T1 age/Cor/TelemetryCollector.h:531 ]: Message from Phusion: End time can not be before or equal to begin time
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:03.1721 3598/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1325 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
[ N 2020-02-12 19:01:05.2266 3627/T5 age/Cor/SecurityUpdateChecker.h:519 ]: Security update check: no update found (next check in 24 hours)
```

**My $PATH**

```
    bash: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/passenger-6.0.4/bin:/root/.nodenv/bin:/root/.rbenv/bin:/root/.nodenv/bin:/root/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin
```

**And my RubyGems Environment**

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.5 (2019-10-01 patchlevel 114) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5
     - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/passenger-6.0.4/bin
     - /root/.nodenv/bin
     - /root/.rbenv/bin
     - /root/.nodenv/bin
     - /root/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@global/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/bin
```

When running **passenger-config-validate-install**, it says everything is okay.

I have been trying to set this up for a whole week, finding debugging pages on GitHub and such, but to no avail.

It is important to notice that I am using **CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)**.

Comment: Hi Paulo, were you able to solve this issue? I am currently facing the exact same problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This turned out to be a bad "telemetry" check back to Phusion Passengers website.  I just disabled the telemetry and it worked fine.

For Apache,  Add this line to your config:
PassengerDisableAnonymousTelemetry on

For Nginx,  Add this line to your config:
passenger_disable_anonymous_telemetry on